# Func cannot be used in other class files in swift

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I have a func it wants to use in other class files

I declare the func to be outside, This method I want to use it in the other two class files , But its not work , Is it where I got it wrong?

```
class BlurEffect{
    var blurEffectView: UIVisualEffectView!

    func blurEffectAnimation(isBlur: Bool, view: UIView) {

        if isBlur {
            let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .light)
            blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
            blurEffectView.frame = view.bounds
            blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
            view.addSubview(blurEffectView)

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0){
                self.blurEffectView.alpha = 0.4
                self.blurEffectView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
            }
        } else {
            blurEffectView.removeFromSuperview()
            blurEffectView.effect = nil
        }

    }   
}
```

I declare the BlurEffect method in this category

```
class ItemCardTableViewController: UITableViewController  {

    var blurEffectView: BlurEffect?

    @objc func addNewItem() {
        blurEffectView?.blurEffectAnimation(isBlur: true)

        let addAlert = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
        addAlert.addTextField { (textfied: UITextField) in
            textfied.addTarget(addAlert, action: #selector(addAlert.textDidChanged), for: .editingChanged)
        }

        let confirm = UIAlertAction(title: "ok", style: .default) { (action: UIAlertAction) in

            guard let title = addAlert.textFields?.first?.text else { return }

            let newItem = ItemCard(title: title, isFinish: false)
            self.dataManager.items.append(newItem)

            let indexPath = IndexPath(row: self.itemCardTableView.numberOfRows(inSection: 0), section: 0)
            self.itemCardTableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .left)
            self.blurEffectView?.blurEffectAnimation(isBlur: false)
        }

        let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "cancle", style: .cancel) { _ in self.blurEffectView?.blurEffectAnimation(isBlur: false)}

        addAlert.addAction(cancel)
        confirm.isEnabled = false
        addAlert.addAction(confirm)
        self.present(addAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

`blurEffectView?.blurEffectAnimation(isBlur: true)` it's not work

Comment: Your `BlurEffect` is a `UIViewController`. Internally, the method you want to use uses its own internal view: `view.addSubview(blurEffectView)`.
Your main `ItemCardTableViewController` view is not affected in any way by the method you wrote.
Long story short: IT IS working, but not on the view you expect.

Comment: I do not understand, and how can fix it, the func has Useful to view

Comment: `var blurEffectView: BlurEffect?` does not initialize it, its nil

Comment: i tried  var blurEffectView = BlurEffect()  also the same

Comment: You have 2 view controllers: `BlurEffect` and `ItemCardTableViewController`. According to your code, you are trying to apply the blur effect on the `ItemCardTableViewController`. The problem is that you are applying it on `BlurEffect`, thats why you don't see any result on the screen.

Comment: ok , I understand , How can I modify the code on the BlurEffect side, which is useful to the view, can not inherit UIviewcontroller

Comment: In addition to @Scriptable comment... Your `blurEffectAnimation` method takes two arguments, but you're trying pass 1.